# Bitwise operations giving unexpected outcomes

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I try to understand the difference between the logical operand `and` and the bitwise operand `&`.
So I wrote two statements and get unexpected outcomes.
I understand the first one and expect the second one would give me the same outcome as the first one.

1. The first one I get the False which is what I want. But the second one I get True which makes me confused.
2. Since `3%3 == 0` return `True`,and `3%5 == 0` return `False`. And `True & False` gives me `False`. Why, when I put them together, do I get the `True`? Can someone explain why the second one gives me the `True` instead of `False`?

   ```
   3 % 3 == 0 and 3 % 5 == 0
   3 % 3 == 0 & 3 % 5 ==0 
   3 % 3 == 0
   3 % 5 == 0
   True & False
   ```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Can you please write the code as part of your question instead of as a screenshot in an external website?

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer,  please fix your question and add the following, your code, your input, the unexpected output, and what you expect. Please read [ask]. Imagine you're asking a question to a busy colleague

Comment: Different operators with different priorities - why would you expect the same output?

Comment: Consider that `(3 % 3 == 0) & (3 % 5 == 0)` does output `False` as expected

Answer (score 5):

Operators priority is probably the source of confusion here.

`&` has **higher** precedence than `==`, whereas `and` has a **lower** one.

This means the second case is the same as `3 % 3 == (0 & 3 % 5) == 0`

If you add more parenthesis to show the order, these are equivalent:

```py
(3 % 3) == (0 & (3 % 5)) == 0
0 == (0 & 3) == 0
0 == 0 == 0  // True
```

Note: the last chain of `==` is interpreted as the equality test between all three operands, and is obviously true here. Thanks @kaya for clarification comment.

Comment: This is half right - an expression like `a == b == c` is not equivalent to `(a == b) == c`, it is equivalent to `(a == b) and (b == c)` except `b` is evaluated only once.

Comment: Why did you remove the additional explaining steps? Looked useful to me

Comment: @lucidbroi did a mistake in order for `==`t (comment from kaya explains it), I'll add the correct ones back now!

Comment: @kaya3 yes indeed, my first draft of example was wrong. Thank you for clear and short explanation

Comment: Among `%`     `==`      `&`, the `%` has the highest precedence. If this is the case, shouldn't be equivalent to (3 % 3 )==( 0 & (3 % 5 ))==0 ?

Comment: @NomardicRoku you are definitely right, I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember than **and** means that both the expressions ***must*** be correct

## `3 % 3 == 0 and 3 % 5 == 0`

```py
print( 3 % 3 )
```

> 0

- Hence, the first part is true

```py
print( 3 % 5)
```

> 3

- Hence, the second part is **False**, since the expression does **not** evaluate to `0`

So if we simplify it, it becomes

```py
3 % 3 == 0 and 3 % 5 == 0

True and False:
```

Both conditions are **not** true, hence the answer is false.

---

## `3 % 3 == 0 & 3 % 5 == 0`

The answer comes when we look at [operator precendence](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm)
**`&` has a higher precedence than `==`**
Hence, the statement is basically

```py
3 % 3 == (0 & 3) % 5 == 0
```

Comment: According to the page you linked, `%` has higher precedence than `&`, so it should be `(3 % 3) == (0 & (3 % 5)) == 0` to be fully verbose.